# how to make full size background image without specific height?

Tags: css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

<style>

body {width:100%;
      height:100%;
      margin:0;
      padding:0;}

#star_box {width:100%;
           height:auto;
           overflow:hidden;
           display:block;
           background-image:url('https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/sappun/promotion/test.jpg') ;
           background-size: cover;
           background-repeat: no-repeat;
           background-position: center top;}

.star {color:white;
       animation-name:zoomin;
       animation-duration:5s;
       text-align:center;
       animation-iteration-count:infinite;}

.star2 {color:white;
       animation-name:zoomin;
       animation-duration:5s;
       text-align:center;
       animation-iteration-count:infinite;
       animation-delay:.5s;}

@keyframes zoomin {
    0%{
 transform: scale(0,0) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
  25%{
   transform: scale(4,4) rotateZ(80deg); 
    }
  50%{
   transform: scale(0,0) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
  100%{
   transform: scale(0,0) rotateZ(0deg);
    }
}

#star_box > p:nth-child(1) {margin-left:450px;
                            margin-top:150px;}

#star_box > p:nth-child(2) {margin-left:400px;
                            margin-top:10px;}
                            
#star_box > p:nth-child(3) {margin-left:-450px;
                            margin-top:350px;}
                            
#star_box > p:nth-child(4) {margin-left:-530px;
                            margin-top:30px;}
                            
#star_box > p:nth-child(5) {margin-left:280px;
                            margin-top:-200px;}                         

#empty_box {width:80%;
            height:1200px;
            display:block;
            margin:0 auto;
            margin-top: -350px;}

#text {text-align:center;
       color:white;
       font-size:50px;
       margin-top:250px;
       opacity:0;
       transition:opacity .3s linear;}
       
#empty_box:hover ~ #text {opacity:1;}      

</style>


</head>
<body>

<div id="star_box">

    <p class="star">&#10022;</p>
    
    <p class="star2">&#10022;</p>
    
    <p class="star">&#10022;</p>
    
    <p class="star2">&#10022;</p>
    
    <p class="star">&#10022;</p>
    
    <div id="empty_box"></div>
    
    <p id="text">今すぐ見る</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Hi! now i have problem with this code to make background to responsive with full size.
so firstly, it has to be responsive for mobile
and secondly, background height be 100% without content so i can see full image all the time.
i already tried background-size:cover but it is not working in my code :(
where should i fix to make background to full size?

any help will so appreciated. thanks! :D

Comment: By full size, you mean full screen or the browser is cutting some part due to `background-size: cover` and you don't want it to do so.

Comment: is "background-size:cover" making it looks like cutting?? i didn't know that;;... i wanna make it full size but if i set some specific number like height:2500px ~ then it 's not be responsive anymore so....:( what how can i make it to full screen?

Comment: Alternative to `background-size: cover` is `background-size: contain` Contan will show the whole image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `height` will be relative to your container, and using `background-size: cover` will stretch your image to match the container, which why both of them don't guarantee the image will be at the size of full screen.

You can use `vh` and `vw` for that, like this:

```css
.img {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? `vh` and `vw` units are not relative to the parent element, use `%` rather use of the units which are relative to the viewport.

Comment: I think he wants full screen, so relative to the viewport should be fine

Comment: Hi! thanks for your help! :D using "vh, vw" way is really nice thanks for let me know about this! :) but it still not be fullsize of the img , i want to see that background as whole img, like when i put <img src="img_link">

Answer (score 1):

Change `background-size: cover;` of id `#star_box` to `background-size: contain;`

```
#star_box {
  background-size: contain;
}
```